# Problem with applet loading on Mac OS x 10.4

Tags: java, macos, applet

I have been working on web application which includes java applet. My app is working fine on PC with different browsers like IE and Firefox. The web application hosted on Linux (Ubuntu).
I had problem on Mac with Firefox. I was unable to load the applet.

This is the error i found in java console.
Java.lang.classNotFoundException web/applets/ImageObsApplet.class

I have hosted the web application on PC windows XP and i am able to load the java applet on Mac system.

#### Update:

I am using J2SE 1.5.0. This does not support on Mac OS X 10.4? I am able to run the application successfully on Mac OS X 10.5.5.

Now I am able to load the applet on MAC OS X 10.4.11.
but i had a problem with applet functionality.
My applet will display the map image. Applet contains the navigation arrow keys at the top left of my applet. These keys will be used to navigate through the map.
The problem is while user using the navigation buttons, the image got squash and stretch.
This is happened only on MAC OS X 10.4.11 and Its working fine on PC and MAC OS X 10.5.5.

Comment: What Java version are you targeting? Java 1.6 is only supported on 64-bit Intel (i.e. Core 2 and Xeon) Macs running Leopard.

Comment: By the way, it's called a Mac. A MAC is a Media Access Controller - i.e. a network card.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but there was a java plugin problem with firefox on mac. I think firefox on 10.4 supports Java 1.4 only. Have you tried with safari?